# Left join only if previous join didn't find anything

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I'm trying to put this as smallest as I can.

--

Let's say I have three tables, table1 table2 and table3. All these tables have a column "organizationID". I also have a table0 which is somehow linked to all of these.

Sometimes, "organizationID" is at table 1, sometimes it's at table 2, sometimes it's at table3.

--

I'm doing something like this:

```
SELECT coalesce(table1.organizationID,coalese(table2.organizationID,coalesce(table3.organizationID,0)))
FROM table0
LEFT JOIN table1 ON (some condition)
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (some condition)
LEFT JOIN table3 ON (some condition)
```

This works. It gives me what I want. The problem is on performance. The database always does all the three joins, even if table1 already had the orgaizationID.

--

I want to modify this select to something like the following:

```
SELECT coalesce(table1.organizationID,coalese(table2.organizationID,coalesce(table3.organizationID,0)))
FROM table0
LEFT JOIN table1 ON (some condition)
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (some condition) AND table1.organizationID IS NULL
LEFT JOIN table3 ON (some condition) AND table2.organizationID IS NULL
```

The problem is that it's still doing all the joins, therefore taking the same amount of time to finish the execution.

Is there any way to prevent the joins from running if previous join suceeded?

--

Thanks a lot in advance.

--

EDIT: The table3 join take a lot of time to be executed. I can't do anything about it. So I want to avoid joining that table if I don't need to(that is, if either table1 or table2 already have the "organizationID" column)

Comment: Are you interested in ONLY one column from `table3` *(organizationID)*, or other columns as well?

Answer (score 0):

The query is going to do all the joins, because all may be needed -- on different rows.

If you really wanted to limited the number of lookups, you could use `case`.  Something like:

```
SELECT . . ., 
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM table1 t1
                          WHERE t1.? = t0.? AND . . .
                         )
             THEN (SELECT ?
                   FROM table1 t1
                   WHERE t1.? = t0.? AND . . .
                  )
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM table1 t2
                          WHERE t2.? = t0.? AND . . .
                         )
             THEN (SELECT ?
                   FROM table2 t2
                   WHERE t2.? = t0.? AND . . .
                  )
           . . .
      END)
FROM table0;
```

However, this will not speed the query.

Instead, you probably just need appropriate indexes to get the performance that you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `IS NULL` checks are incomplete.  If `t1` is joined successfully, `t2.organization` will be `NULL` and cause you to check `t3` redundantly.

Try this first?

```
SELECT
    coalesce(table1.organizationID,coalese(table2.organizationID,coalesce(table3.organizationID,0)))
FROM
          table0
LEFT JOIN table1 ON (some condition)
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (some condition) AND table1.organizationID IS NULL
LEFT JOIN table3 ON (some condition) AND table1.organizationID IS NULL AND table2.organizationID IS NULL
```

Otherwise, you MIGHT be able to convince the optimiser to short-circuit *(Not join if not necessary)* by using lateral joins?

```
SELECT
  table3.organizationID
FROM
  table0
LEFT JOIN
  table1
    ON (some condition)
LEFT LATERAL JOIN
(
  SELECT table2.organizationID FROM table2 WHERE (some condition) AND table1.organizationID IS     NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT table1.organizationID             WHERE                      table1.organizationID IS NOT NULL
)
  table2 ON true
LEFT LATERAL JOIN
(
  SELECT table3.organizationID FROM table3 WHERE (some condition) AND table2.organizationID IS     NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT table2.organizationID             WHERE                      table2.organizationID IS NOT NULL
)
  table3 ON true
```